# How to say "they didn't leave him a penny"?

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot

I want to say:

> His parents were very poor and they didn't leave him a penny.

I mean to say that when his parents died he didn't inherit anything.
I would translate it like this:

> Ses parents étaient très pauvres et ils ne lui ont laissé un sou.

I'm not sure if there's a better solution...

Merci d'avance pour votre aide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il y a plus idiomatique

> Ses parents étaient très pauvres et l'ont laissé sans le sou.

https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sans_le_sou

Comment: Du français correct, ça l'est…mais sa qualité de plus grande idiomaticité, c'est autre chose …je crois que vous faites référence ici à de subtiles différences de registre que personne ou seulement des spécialistes considèrent et qui, bien  que je les trouve perceptibles restent pour moi dans le domaine de l'intangible quant à la caractérisation précise qui convient pour y référer.

Comment: Il y a une différence entre « ne pas recevoir un sou » et « être laissé sans le sou », ce qui fait de quelqu'un un sans-le-sou; cela ne semble pas exact parce que « pauvre » ne signifie pas vraiment « sans le sou »,  qui signifie « plus pauvre  que pauvre »; ne verriez-vous pas les choses ainsi ?

Comment: J'allais pas aussi loin, le sou n'existe plus en France depuis la troisième république il y a 150 ans, l'usage d'expression avec sou (ou sol) est donc idiomatique.

Comment: Ce n'est pas la question; vous dites « **plus** idiomatique », mais c'est plus idiomatique que quoi ? Il ne peut s'agir que de l'autre utilisation de sou, dans l'autre réponse; je dis donc que des deux il n'y en a pas une plus idiomatique que l'autre et que vous saisissez quelque chose d'autre qu'une qualité d'idiomaticité, que par ailleurs  je trouve intéressante de considérer mais que je connais pas de nom.

Comment: Je suis bien conscient que l'on peut dire « je n'ai pas le sou. » et « Je n'ai pas un sou. »; mais je ne vois pas ce qui concerne l'idiomaticité, la question de combien plus approprié du point de vue expression en français serait la première forme.

Comment: Diriez-vous « d'un registre plus gallique » ?

Answer (score 3):

C'est exact ; je ne vois rien d'autre qui puisse améliorer cette traduction (mis à part qu'il faut la locution de négation complète).

Ses parents étaient très pauvres et ils ne lui ont pas laissé un sou.

Comment: Fwiw, I prefer your answer, for as you note elsewhere: "Il y a une différence entre «ne pas recevoir un sou» et «être laissé sans le sou»". BUT I don't understand your "pauvre vs plus pauvre que pauvre" reasoning as to the importance of that difference.  Imo, the best point to make regarding that difference is that a rich person (or even one who's not penniless) is not left/rendered penniless just because their poor parents don't leave them anything (but "NEVERMIND" if "l'ont laissé sans le sou=the parents left the earth penniless," for Arch's answer & your point would then make sense to me!).

Comment: @PapaPoule It's easy : the young French prentice or someone on welfare is poor but still can have a decent living; poorer than that poor individual is the beggar at a street corner; logic is being totally ignored in this locution; it is a valid figure of speech but I'm not too sure it belongs to formal writing (I think it wise to dispense with it in that type of writing until better advised). Subtle are those two last points … Yes I would have done well to make this important remark (leave them nothing, not necessarily penniless), but it's not necessary anymore.